# Image Classification with C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, classification

I am scanning ID cards and there are 10 types of cards that are being scanned. Assume for example 10 driver licenses from 10 different states. Can somebody guide me on what would be the easiest approach to classify them using C#?

Comment: get a big training set, and then use a supervised machine learning to predict type of driver license from the image

Comment: May be in that basic case it's easier to use some text recognition library and then look for state name in that text. Text recognition will not be perfect, so look for the closest to state name text.

Answer (score 0):

There are some online/offline ready to use classifiers take a look:

[Accord Framework](http://www.accord-framework.net)

[Azure Vision API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)

[Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwwLHLBRDEq9DQxK2I_p8BEiQA3UDVDirl_foegaUt-Zc5JKeKYvD3VD9IfJs4QcBuo1Xh1cgaAjMw8P8HAQ&dclid=CM-q4OnakNUCFQmrdwodXbwAQg)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that in the states you have a driver number and  a passport number while not a c# answer and more generic I would suggest you use OCR and look for the passport number and or driver number

You could follow something like this article on code project which would allow you to scan the documents.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160868/A-C-Project-in-Optical-Character-Recognition-OCR-U

However I am not sure how you would tell the different states I would to be honest give this over to the user to select the state that they are from during the entry process.